# Coffee machine powering faster than light communications

Tags: story-identification

I can't recall the name of a short story I read, and Google is drawing a blank for me.

I can only remember one detail that stuck in my mind:

- There was a coffee machine that powered Faster Than Light Communications. (!)

I am also sure that I read it within the last ten years.

Comment: It makes me think both of the Nutrimatic that stole all the processing power from the Heart of Gold AND of the 'Bistromath' drive, in the [HHGTTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HHGTTG) series... But it doesn't quite fit.

Comment: Also in the HHGTTG the infinite probability drive was created by computing just how improbable it was and feeding that number into a *finite* improbability generator which also made use of a nice hot cup of tea as a Brownian motion generator. But again, it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: It definitely wasn't H2G2, although it is an awesome book/trilogy/series

Comment: If it was only light speed communications, there's always *Spaceballs*: "You call that a radar screen?"  "No sir, we call it Mr. Coffee."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This story doesn't contain FTL comms 'come coffee machine', but it does feature someone *who thinks* that a coffee machine is a FTL comms device.

It's [Defending Elysium](http://coppermind.net/wiki/Defending_Elysium) by Brandon Sanderson.

> The relevant quote is
>
> > Coln frowned, then eyed the coffee machine. “So, it's not the FTL comm unit...”
>
> — [John Rennie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/coffee-machine-powering-faster-than-light-communications/38525#comment73339_38525)

Comment: Note that the question states FTL comms (i.e. ansible equivalent) not FTL propulsion.

Comment: *Defending Elysium* fits the description. The relevant quote is "Coln frowned, then eyed the coffee machine. “So, it's not the FTL comm unit...”"

Comment: Ahhh, that's the one. I'll have to re-read that. Strange how my mind flipped it around.